# Make PyQt 4.10 (or higher) on RHEL6 with Qt 4.6.2

Tags: qt, pyqt4

I would like to install PyQt 4.10.0 (>=) in order to meet Gnuradio requirements on my RHEL6 machine.
I have Qt 4.6.2 and Sip 4.16.2, but when I run make it ends with following error:

```
qpycore_chimera.cpp: In member function ‘void Chimera::set_flag()’:
qpycore_chimera.cpp:557: error: ‘struct _pyqt4ClassTypeDef’ has no member named ‘qt4_flags’
```

The configuration script doesn't complain about Qt version althought it seems that only that can be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

As was suggested on PyQt [mailing list](https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2015-September/036482.html), the problem was inappropriate version of SIM.